# Where are system UI image files stored?

Tags: macos, filesystem, ui

On OS X Yosemite, where are the image files for system UI elements such as buttons, sliders, menus, traffic lights, etc. stored?

Comment: or here /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeechObjects.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictationServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources

Comment: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/sartfile‌​s <-- This path does not exist on Yosemite. Even if it did, or even if you are referring to the SArtFile.bin file that resides in the Resources directory there, you still have to be able to extract the files from that encrypted archive. And those files are not Yosemite resources (they are Mavericks resources), which are located at the path I specified in my answer below.

Comment: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeechObjects.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/‌​DictationServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources <-- This path does not contain any image files or encrypted art archives. (At least on Yosemite.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ThemeEngine](https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine) is an open source utility that can open and modify these themes.

Answer (score 0):

The resources are stored at

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources
```

Note there is currently no known way to extract the art from the `.car` files, as far as I can tell.